# SESSIONS_PER_USER limit with nodejs

Tags: node.js, oracle, ubuntu-14.04, node-oracledb

I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of weeks:

For some reason, our nodejs script which is connecting to a oracle database in another machine started erroring with SESSIONS_PER_USER limit, but we don't have any other connection opened to the database. I tried another user we have but it returns the exact same error.

The most weird part is that this service has been running for weeks and it is the first time it gives us this error.

We use the oracledb (https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) module to connect to the database.

We asked the support team but apparently they can use our users to connect the db, but when it comes to use the accounts in our machine (ubuntu server 14.04) it gives this error. I tried searching for a possible "cached" sessions or connections inside our machine but I haven't found a lot of help regarding this matter on google...

I would really appreciate if someone can give me some help regarding this issue, since I don't know what else I can do about.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your session limit? I'm not sure about that specific provider, but in my past experience, providers will open several sessions when you connect and store them in a connection pool for re-use. Node may be doing the same.

Comment: It is 2, the sys admins just told me that the day it stopped working they changed from "unlimited" to 2, but anyways now it shouldn't give any session_limit error since we don't have any connection.

Comment: Unless node stores some data in the local cache... but I haven't found anything regarding that. I'm clueless at the moment :S

Comment: Try increasing the session size to 15. Again, I'm not sure about Node, but in ASP.NET, connection pools default to 10.

Comment: They won't do it for security reasons, there are many other users accessing this database and want to prevent us to have multiple connections open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proceed to answer this question myself, since what happened is that the IT team changed some configuration the exact day we started having problems... User config from UNLIMITED requests to 2. It happened that in our code we were using an async (nodejs) method called eachLimit, where you can assign a limit iteration count, and it was 2 but somehow made it crash anyways (even with the limit being 2).

The solution: removing the iterator and doing it manually 1 by 1 (only 4 elements), anyways it is still harsh, since we have to do this task every day.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

2 is a ridiculously low SESSIONS_PER_USER value for *any* profile.  Raise it back to UNLIMITED for your application profile.

There are many legitimate reasons why an application or a user needs multiple connections:

1. **Background sessions** - Many tools and applications automatically create one or more background sessions.  This may allow your IDE to run concurrent statements, or might be used to asynchronously retrieve metadata when you open windows.
2. **Debugging** - Oracle automatically creates background sessions when debugging.
3. **Parallelism** - Parallel statements can easily spawn dozens or hundreds of sessions.
4. **Sniped connections** - If your database has set an inactive timeout some sessions will get killed but not immediately removed.  They sometimes show up as "sniped" in `GV$SESSION`, and there's no way to get rid of them short of restarting the database or waiting.  Those sessions still count against your limit even though there is absolutely nothing connected from the client side.
5. **Connection pools** - I'm not familiar with your application settings but I assumed most applications these days automatically create multiple connections.
6. **Day-to-day use** - Lots of people frequently connect to a database with different tools at the same time, or with one tool with more than window open.

If someone says, "but our security rules!", ask them to read the [DoD Security Technical Implementation Guide (STIG)](https://nvd.nist.gov/ncp/checklist/667/download/2540).  It's almost certain that their rules, or the results of some security audit, were based on that file.  There's nothing in there against having a huge or unlimited number of concurrent sessions.  You just have to justify it in your site-specific rules.

---

2 is also a ridiculously low value for preventing unnecessary calls or preventing a large number of open connections.

It's difficult to predict how different programs will break when they hit that limit.  It's not that surprising that you can't find the active sessions - perhaps the program tries to automatically spawn X threads and immediately kills them all if some of them fail.

Ask your administrators to explain *exactly* what they are trying to accomplish and why.

My guess is that the database is configured incorrectly and there are arbitrarily scarce resources.  For example, the parameters PROCESSES and SESSIONS usually default to low value.  If those values are kept at something small, like 100, then there will be problems and users have to fight over connections.

It can be helpful to reduce the number of sessions in a database.  But a limit of 2 is unrealistic.  I've seen plenty of databases running on old hardware with thousands of sessions.

Comment: I am totally agree with you, but apparently they do it because many users around the company needs access to this db (production) and don't want overload it with innecessary calls. In this case it is a cron job that runs once a day. The most weird thing is that when they look for open connections for both my colleague's user and mine there aren't any active!